# Move moved long and lat to their own position

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, latitude-longitude, replace, move

I have a dataset with point that have fields containing latitude and longitude.

I have displaced some points (up to 2 mts) and saved the modification. The field containing the original lat long in the data is not changed but the geometry of the point is changed.

How can i move the point back to their location defined in the fields long and lat that haven't been changed ?

Comment: And clarify a bit : you moved some points and you want to update your table's content with the new coordinates of these points ?

Comment: we can generate the lat long with calculate geometry but i need old lat longs not the moved once.

Comment: Then just reload the original data?

Comment: I suppose that "own" in the title was meant for "original" ?

Comment: @Snaileater yes!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you want to place your point based on a field containing lat and long. There are multiple ways to do it with code and editing direcly the layer.

What I would suggest is to build a temporary new layer based on the field and then choose either to replace your layer or only replace some point on your layer.

Steps :

1. Open Menu > Processing > tool box > Vector creation > Create point layer from table
2. Source layer = the layer you want to edit, x = lon, y = lat, SCR = 4326 (i assume you are using lat and long). Then "Execute".
3. You have now a new layer. Select the point you want to get and copy them.
4. On your previous layer toggle edition and then paste the "new" points and remove the old version of these points (to make no conflict).
5. Do a quick verification (number of points unchanged, overlapping...) and then save your modification on the layer.

Comment: its working Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the original dataset, just export the current out as a table and recreate the data using the unmodded lat lon attributes.